# Image files stored in src/webapp not showing in frontend when run docker container

Tags: java, docker, jar

I stored some images in my java webapp, but the images were not display on the frontend when I packaged them into jar and created a docker image. How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be useful to show, how you call the images? What is the context path?

Comment: Add more details about your Dockerfile and any additional info you may find helpful